# Program never enters in the virtual destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am just trying to understand some concepts of inheritance/polymorphism and tried to inherit a class from `std::string` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass : public std::string
{
    virtual ~MyClass()
    {
        cout << "Inside Virutal Destructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string *s = new MyClass();  
    delete s;

    cout << "Program started" << endl; //NEVER REACHES HERE
}
```

**QUESTION:** With the above code, I was expecting a call to the virtual destructor at the line `delete s` but as soon as the program reaches there, the program enters into some undefined state (i.e. doesn't crash, doesn't go forward). Where is the program stuck?

Comment: The destructor of std::basic_string is *not* defined virtual.

Comment: Many (possibly most) standard library classes are not designed to be derived from.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I understand, as I said, this is just for testing and understanding.

Comment: @skm There is no problem in inheriting from `std::string` itself. You just cannot use the derived object in a polymorphic way, since `std::string` is not a polymorphic type (has no virtual member functions).

Comment: @skm Have you checked the question I pointed to? There, you find an answer, which, shortly, is: **undefined behavior**. If you do not understand what does it mean, check questions about undefined behavior. (It basically means that your program may behave in any way and asking about it **makes no sense**.)

Comment: @DanielLangr: Yes, I checked the answer you pointed. I have myself written in the original post that the program enters in an undefined state. I am just wondering, what it is doing exactly? Is it stuck in some loop or some lock etc.?

Comment: @DanielLangr: Ok, I understand. Thanks:)

Comment: @skm You're welcome. Here is an additional question you may be interested in: [Should I try to explain undefined behaviour?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271372/580083).

Comment: @DanielLangr: I got confused again. The destructor of the parent class i.e. `std::string` is not virtual so, why isn't it executed when I reach the statement `delete s`?

Comment: @DanielLangr: Yes, I checked the debugging and as mentioned in my question, it does not take me anywhere....because the program enter in the undefined state.

Comment: @skm Because the C++ Standard does not say it shall be called. It simply says that `delete s;` itself [causes undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3.sentence-1).

Answer (score 0):

The standard class template `std::basic_string` does not have a virtual destructor. So the class does not have a pointer to the destructor in the table of virtual function pointers. As a result the virtual destructor of the derived class will not be called.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "A::f()\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual void f() const { std::cout << "virtual B::f()\n"; }
};

struct C : B
{
    void f() const override { std::cout << "virtual C::f()\n"; }
};


int main() 
{
    C c;

    A *ac = &c;
    B *bc = &c;

    ac->f();
    bc->f();

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A::f()
virtual C::f()
```

Class A has a non-virtual function f.

Class B has a virtual function f that hides the non-virtual function of the class A and does not override it.

Class C overrides the virtual function of the class B.

Comment: @Jarod42The template class basic_string does not have virtual functions.

Comment: Considering your sample example, the `delete s` statement in my program should have been executed without any problem because the destructor of `std::string` is not virtual. But why isn't the destructor of `std::string`  called?

Comment: @skm it is. But the destructor of the derived class is not. Such deletion by pointer to base class of a class without virtual destructor actually has undefined behavior according to the C++ Standard.